# Calendar grid in WPF application

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout, grid

I want to make calendar application with layout like in windows calendar
[image]

I wondering what controls can i use to do this layout in wpf application. I was thinking about grid and text blocks in this block but this doesn't work with multiple grid cell. I need my event in calendar can be split with multiple cell in this grid.
What can I do to achieve the same layout in WPF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are in the right track with the `Grid` for layouting. `Grid` is highly customisable that should support your need for multiple cell share. Try the `Grid.ColumnSpan` property. You should set up your `ColumnDefinition` properly to be able to use it properly.

Look into the Examples in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.grid?view=netframework-4.7.2#examples) for more details.
This is also from the official site:

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ShowGridLines="True" Width="250" Height="100">
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>

      <TextBlock FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="0">2005 Products Shipped</TextBlock>
      <TextBlock FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">Quarter 1</TextBlock>
      <TextBlock FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">Quarter 2</TextBlock>
      <TextBlock FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2">Quarter 3</TextBlock>
      <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0">50000</TextBlock>
      <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">100000</TextBlock>
      <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2">150000</TextBlock>
      <TextBlock FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="3">Total Units: 300000</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider buying a telerik licence if i was given that requirement.

Take a look at this https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30329/Creating-an-Outlook-Calendar-using-WPF-Part-1

Since you seem to require less than half hour positioning and half column width I'm not so sure grid is the way to go. Could well prove easier to position and drag round on a canvas. Then do some calculations to detect overlap and "snap" to columns.
Draw the lines onto a bitmap.

The appointments should probably  be a user control rather than just a textblock.